# exercise: limit of generalised integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

please help me with this!I really can't solve this..every opinion is worthy [image]

Comment: Hint: L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: how I can show that the limit of integral is +8?

Comment: @user136055 the limit of the integral is NOT 8.

Comment: Why do you believe that the number $8$ has a privilege?

Comment: how i can show this : ∫(...)ds→∞ in order to use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: oh, he meant $\infty$. it is $+\infty$ because $f$ is increasing.

Comment: In case, you don't know how to use $\TeX$ to type math symbols, just use the word "infinity"

Answer (score 1):

$$\large\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_0^xe^sf(s)\,ds}{x^2}$$

Applying L'Hospital's rule,

$$\large\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf(x)}{2x}$$

Applying L'Hospital's rule again,

$$\large\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x(f(x)+f'(x))}{2}$$

Obviously, this limit is $+\infty$

Comment: thank you so much. how I explain:1) the limit of numerator is infinity, 2)this obviously killed me

Comment: Ι can.. but my Corrigendum maybe has different opinion. thank you very much!

Comment: @user136055 i had to google that word. xp

Comment: "corrigentum"? I google it too! the guy who corrects the texts